# Yii2 cannot register shutdown function in controller action

Tags: php, error-handling, yii2, execution-time

I have a controller action as follows:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    set_time_limit(1);
    register_shutdown_function(function()
    {
        var_dump('shutdown');
    });

    while(true){} //infinite loop
}
```

And i still get the fatal error "Maximum execution time of 1 second exceeded"

If i don't sleep or make the execution time to exceed, the shutdown function is called.
According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#33575 and several examples from the internet, the shutdown should be called even if the execution time is exceeded.

How should i handle the execution time error?

Answer (score 1):

I bet PHP throws a fatal error *before* running your shutdown function. Something like "Fatal error: Maximum execution time exceeded".  Yii's [error handler](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-errorhandler.html) catches all PHP errors, displays error message and dies before PHP gets a chance to run your function. That way your function never gets executed.

There are several solutions to this problem. First, you can disable Yii's handling of PHP errors altogether by adding this line to `index.php`.

```
define(YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER, false);
```

Second, you can try disabling error messages in php.ini using [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) or [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) directives.

Third, you can catch PHP errors using a try-catch block and catching the [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.errorexception.php) class. Just catch the exception and do nothing about it: